# Exception related to PerRequestLifetimeManager on SignalR integrated with Unity

Tags: c#, signalr, unity-container

I'm currently having the following exception thrown from times to times, but I could not identify when it occurs and more importantly, why. My bet is that it's probably related to Unity my dependency injection container and the way I'm registering the types. Here's the error:

```
The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.UnityPerRequestHttpModule.GetDictionary(HttpContext context) +195
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc.UnityPerRequestHttpModule.GetValue(Object lifetimeManagerKey) +50
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.LifetimeStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +146
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +396
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +206
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +33
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +337
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +396
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +206
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +33
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +337
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +396
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +130
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +212
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +33
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +337
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +396
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +238

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "TradeForce.Portal.Hubs.ExecutionReportsHub", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate synchronization context.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving TradeForce.Portal.Hubs.ExecutionReportsHub,(none)
  Resolving parameter "iExecutionReportsBusiness" of constructor TradeForce.Portal.Hubs.ExecutionReportsHub(TradeForce.Dominio.Interfaces.Business.Reports.IExecutionReportsBusiness iExecutionReportsBusiness, TradeForce.Dominio.Interfaces.Repository.NH.IUsers iUsers, TradeForce.Dominio.Interfaces.Repository.NH.ICollaborators iCollaborators, TradeForce.Infraestrutura.Persistencia.NHibernateUtil.SessionProvider sessionProvider)
    Resolving TradeForce.Business.Entities.Reports.ExecutionReportsBusiness,(none) (mapped from TradeForce.Dominio.Interfaces.Business.Reports.IExecutionReportsBusiness, (none))
    Resolving parameter "iExecutionReports" of constructor TradeForce.Business.Entities.Reports.ExecutionReportsBusiness(TradeForce.Dominio.Interfaces.Repository.NH.Reports.IExecutionReports iExecutionReports)
      Resolving TradeForce.Infraestrutura.DAO.NH.Reports.DAOExecutionReports,(none) (mapped from TradeForce.Dominio.Interfaces.Repository.NH.Reports.IExecutionReports, (none))
      Resolving parameter "sessionProvider" of constructor TradeForce.Infraestrutura.DAO.NH.Reports.DAOExecutionReports(TradeForce.Infraestrutura.Persistencia.NHibernateUtil.SessionProvider sessionProvider)
        Resolving TradeForce.Infraestrutura.Persistencia.NHibernateUtil.SessionProvider,(none)
]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +500
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +20
   TradeForce.Portal.Helpers.UnityHubActivator.Create(HubDescriptor descriptor) +108
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.CreateHub(IRequest request, HubDescriptor descriptor, String connectionId, StateChangeTracker tracker, Boolean throwIfFailedToCreate) +601
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.OnReceived(IRequest request, String connectionId, String data) +614
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.<>c__DisplayClassc.<ProcessRequestPostGroupRead>b__7() +41
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod(Func`1 func) +25
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +181
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +69
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.<ProcessSendRequest>d__12.MoveNext() +944
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +181
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +599
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +181
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +870
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +181
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +203
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +181
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +193
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +96
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +509
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +146
```

Here's the SignalR hub that is making use of Unity:

```
public class ExecutionReportsHub : BaseHub
{
    private readonly IExecutionReportsBusiness _iExecutionReportsBusiness;
    private readonly IUsers _iUsers;
    private readonly ICollaborators _iCollaborators;
    private readonly SessionProvider _sessionProvider;

    public ExecutionReportsHub(IExecutionReportsBusiness iExecutionReportsBusiness, IUsers iUsers, ICollaborators iCollaborators, SessionProvider sessionProvider)
    {
        _iExecutionReportsBusiness = iExecutionReportsBusiness;
        _iUsers = iUsers;
        _iCollaborators = iCollaborators;
        _sessionProvider = sessionProvider;
    }

    // More code...
}
```

The types registration:

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterInstance(new SessionFactoryProvider());
        container.RegisterType<SessionProvider>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<IUsers, DAOUsers>();
        container.RegisterType<ICollaborators, DAOCollaborators>();
        container.RegisterType<IExecutionReportsBusiness, ExecutionReportsBusiness>();

        container.RegisterType<IHubActivator, UnityHubActivator>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ExecutionReportsHub, ExecutionReportsHub>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        // Other unrelated types being registered...
    }
}
```

The error is occurring during the execution of one of the hub methods from a client-side call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't have per request in hub. [Due to SignalR internals, there is no support in SignalR for per-request lifetime dependencies.](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/signalr.html)

Comment: Thanks @ErkanDemirel I will take a look into that and then report here if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to **not** control the lifetime of a hub. This is managed by the pipeline.

From the the API Guide: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubclass

> You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its methods from your own
>   code on the server; all that is done for you by the SignalR Hubs
>   pipeline. SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time
>   it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a client connects,
>   disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.
>
> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them
>   to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the
>   server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your
>   Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple
>   connections and method calls, use some other method such as a
>   database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class
>   that does not derive from Hub. If you persist data in memory, using a
>   method such as a static variable on the Hub class, the data will be
>   lost when the app domain recycles.

You can still use Unity with the `HubActivator`, which can have a `LifeTimeManager`. But when you're trying to manage the lifetime of the hubs you will probably run in to unexpected behaviors after a while.

And using the `PerRequestLifeTimeManager` will not work out of the box with SignalR and hubs. Partly because of the HttpContext. It uses the `UnityPerRequestHttpModule`, which in turn is using `HttpContext.Current`.

```
internal static void SetValue(object lifetimeManagerKey, object value)
{
  Dictionary<object, object> dictionary = UnityPerRequestHttpModule.GetDictionary(HttpContext.Current);
  if (dictionary == null)
  {
    dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    HttpContext.Current.Items[UnityPerRequestHttpModule.ModuleKey] = (object) dictionary;
  }
  dictionary[lifetimeManagerKey] = value;
}
```

And `HttpContext.Current` is always null in a Hub. You might be able to create your own implementation using `Context.Request.GetHttpContext()`.

However, if you really need to manage the lifetime of the hubs you can create a HubContainer. I did this in one project when we needed to control the hubs.

```
public class HubActivator : IHubActivator
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IHubContainer<ExecutionReportsHub> _hubContainer;

    public HubActivator(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        _hubContainer = container.Resolve<IHubContainer<ExecutionReportsHub>>();
    }

    public IHub Create(HubDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        object hub = _container.Resolve(descriptor.HubType) ?? Activator.CreateInstance(descriptor.HubType);
        if (hub is ExecutionReportsHub)
        {
            _hubContainer.Add(hub as ExecutionReportsHub);
        }
        return hub as IHub;
    }
}

public class ExecutionReportsHubContainer : IHubContainer<ExecutionReportsHub>
{
    public ExecutionReportsHubContainer()
    {
        _hubs = new List<ExecutionReportsHub>();
    }

    private  IList<ExecutionReportsHub> _hubs { get; set; }

    public void Add(ExecutionReportsHub hub)
    {
        _hubs.Add(hub);
    }

    public void Remove(ExecutionReportsHub hub)
    {
        _hubs.Remove(hub);
    }

    public void Dispose(string connectionId)
    {
        IEnumerable<ExecutionReportsHub> hubs = _hubs.Where(x => x.ConnectionId.Equals(connectionId)).ToList();
        foreach (var hub in hubs)
        {
            hub.Detach();
            Remove(hub);
            hub.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public interface IHubContainer<T> where T : IHub
{
    void Dispose(string connectionId);
    void Remove(IFlowHub flowHub);
    void Add(IFlowHub flowHub);
}
```

And your registrations:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IHubContainer<ExecutionReportsHub>, ExecutionReportsHubContainer >(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
unityContainer.RegisterType<IHubActivator, HubActivator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```